# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input. input

Tags: javascript, html

I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

I don't know what I am missing

`<input class="myButton"  type="button" name="slaapkamer1aan" value="AAN" onclick="slaapkameron("slaapkamer1")">`

```
var kamer = document.getElementById(x);
            if (kamer.src.match("lichtUit.png")) {
                kamer.src = "lichtAan.png";
            }
            else {
                kamer.src = "lichtAan.png";
            }

        <?php slaapkameraan();?>
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: `onclick="slaapkameron("slaapkamer1")"` read it three times and you will probably know by yourself.

Comment: Also you have an extra `}` - also you do know that your `onclick="slaapkameron(...` is not going to trigger your PHP ` <?php slaapkameraan();?>`?

Comment: The attribute `onclick="slaapkameron("` does not contain valid JavaScript. Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.